# How can I create a rewrite that redirects all traffic from subdomains to the root/apex domain?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, azure-application-gateway

I have a very simple application gateway that has two listeners, one for 80 and one for 443. Two rules that either allow you to the backend pool with the website, or redirects you from 80 to 443.

I'm trying to set up a rewrite rule that basically converts any traffic to *.example.org and send it instead to example.org.

I have set up a rewrite rule that includes both routing rules and goes like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SPth.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITJPt.png)

The header value in THEN action is {http_resp_Location_1}://example.org{http_resp_Location_2}  (yes I see it's misspelled in the image)

I'm pretty new to doing ANYTHING with headers at all, and regex. Is this the correct approach to what I'm trying to achieve?